# Android: how to change a low quality image to the hi quality one when the animation stops in gallery?

Tags: android, image, lazy-loading, listener, gallery

I want to do an image gallery like in iphone. I want to show low quality (pre-resized) images and when the image is active I want to process the big image and show the result in the gallery.

I have two questions. How to attach a listener on the animation stop in gallery? And how to access an image after this action?

Comment: You can use the Media.Thumbnails content provider for the Slideshow and Media.Images when the slideshow is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an AnimationListener on your animation, and override the onAnimationEnd method.

From http://www.roosmaa.net/animation-ended-callback/ :

```
ImageView viewN = ..;
Animation animN = ...;
Drawable myNewDrawable = ...;
animN.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    // ...
    void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
    {
        //Do your work here.
        viewN.setDrawable(myNewDrawable);
        return;
    }
    // ...
});
viewN.startAnimation(animN);
```